# How to separate plotted lines in gnuplot python when plotting in 3d from array of arrays?

Tags: python, plot, gnuplot

I want to create a 3d plot of plots changing over time. My problem is that since the set of data has the same dimension, it connects the points on y axis creating a surface.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, math
import Gnuplot, Gnuplot.funcutils
import numpy

def generatePlot3D(filename,*y):
    plot = Gnuplot.Gnuplot()
    plot("set terminal pngcairo size 640,480 enhanced font 'Verdana,10")
    plot("set output '{}'".format(filename))
    plot("set border 4095 front linetype 0 linewidth 1.000")
    plot("set view 60,30")
    plot("set logscale z")
    plot("set ztics offset 1")
    plot("set zrange [1:100000]")
    plot("set multiplot")
    for y1 in y :
        plot.splot(Gnuplot.Data(y1,using=(1,2,3), with_="lines lc rgb 'red'"))
    plot("unset multiplot")
    return

array2d = [
        [[1,0,2],[2,0,5],[3,0,15],[4,0,200],[5,0,150],[6,0,2]],
        [[1,1,5],[2,1,25],[3,1,250],[4,1,5],[5,1,90],[6,1,32]],
        [[1,2,8],[2,2,50],[3,2,80],[4,2,1],[5,2,8],[6,2,6]] 
          ]         
generatePlot3D("3d.png",array2d)
```

The plot looks like this:

[image: Example figures python gnuplot]

but I don't want those connecting lines on y axis. I know that if I give the data from file, if I separate with two line the sets it won't connect. How can I achieve that when plotting from data without writing into a file?